# Using webapp2 session as namespace name. How?

Tags: google-app-engine, session, namespaces, webapp2

I have an application which is school based. Each tenant is a different school and to access the application all users for each school have the same password.

Alongside this each school user has to have a google email if they want access to the application. So the application first checks they are a google user, checks wether they are a school user and finally checks that their google email is in the school user list before they are allowed access to any page.

The school user part is using session data from webapp2 sessions to ensure each request they have appropriate access

```
class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def dispatch(self):
    # Get a session store for this request.
    self.session_store = sessions.get_store(request=self.request)

    try:
        # Dispatch the request.
        webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
    finally:
        # Save all sessions.
        self.session_store.save_sessions(self.response)

@webapp2.cached_property
def session(self):
    # Returns a session using the default cookie key.
    return self.session_store.get_session()
```

When a user logins I check the password then create a session which checks their password / user combination every request.

```
def check_u(self):
    try:
        uid = self.session.get('user')
        parent = self.session.get('school-id')
        udl = m.models.User.by_id(int(uid),parent)
        if uid and udl:
            return udl
        else:
            return False
    except (TypeError,AttributeError):
        return False
```

A parent datastore entity for each different school is used called MetaSchool which I have been currently using to ensure that there is no data leak across schools. Each datastore entry uses this parent session key as a way of setting the datastore entry with MetaSchool as parent then using this session key again to read back this data.

This method works but is onerous. I would like to use namespace as a way of separating the data but would like to use the Metaschool id as the name.

```
def namespace_manager_default_namespace_for_request():
    ### Here I need to get ------ parent = self.session.get('school-id')
    ### use this session to gain the MetaSchool key id
    ### Set this as the namespace name
```

Basically trying to emulate from the docs the below scenario

```
from google.appengine.api import users

def namespace_manager_default_namespace_for_request():
     # assumes the user is logged in.
     return users.get_current_user().user_id()
```

I am having difficulty getting the session data from Handler object???
Any thoughts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with.

```
from google.appengine.api import namespace_manager
from webapp2_extras import sessions

def namespace_manager_default_namespace_for_request():
    session = sessions.get_store()
    s = session.get_session()
    name = s.get('key')
    if name:
        return name
    else:
        return namespace_manager.set_namespace('string')
```

Comment: if this is working right for you, please accept this self-answer per normal stackoverflow etiquette, thanks

Comment: Yep just did, but had to wait a few days